# haskell parse error on input "showMapping'"

Tags: function, haskell, syntax, compiler-errors, parse-error

I'm trying to create a Haskell function that can be used to output the contents of a mapping. However, I'm receiving a parse error, which says "`parse error on input showMapping'`", without much information. The code is given below. Where would be the mistake that causes this error?

```
showMapping :: (Show a, Show b) => Map a b -> String
showMapping m = "{ " ++ showMapping' m ++ " }"
      where showMapping' MapSentinel = ""
        showMapping' (MapElem a b MapSentinel) =
                  concat [show a, " -> ", show b]
        showMapping' (MapElem a b rest) =
                  concat [show a, " -> ", show b,
                          ", ", showMapping rest]
```

Comment: looks like an indentation issue - each of those `showMapping'` equations should start at the same horizontal position

Comment: Yes, the problem was solved when I aligned these equations, thank you. However, I don't quite understand indentation in Haskell, is there a general rule in cases such as this?

Comment: You can find the exact rules in the Haskell Report. Section 2.7 gives some rules of thumb https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-210002.7 while the precise rules can be found in Section 10.3 https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-17800010.3